About a functional equation
Problem: Let $(f, g)$ be a pair of function that satisfies the following:

$f, g: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$
$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+, f(xy + f(x)) = xf(y) + g(x)$

Find all possible $(f, g)$ pairs with the previous conditions.
My attempt

I try to prove that $f$ is monotone increasing, by using a polynomial approach: Let $x_1 > x_2$, then there exists a single real root, $r_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, to the following linear equation: $t[f(x_1)-f(x_2)] + x_1 - x_2 = 0$. Since $x_1 > x_2$, therefore $r_0[f(x_1)-f(x_2)] < 0$. If $f(x_1) - f(x_2) < 0 \Rightarrow r_0 > 0 \Rightarrow f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2 - x_1)/r_0$, which is negative, then $f$ is monotone increasing.
I later found out that my approach is somewhat wrong, and I hope to use another polynomial approach, with quadratic and roots similar to what I used.

I hope you folks can help me in:

The principled way to solve this functional equation, because this is the first time I ever faced a multi-function equation.

Also on how to correct my approach and/or find a way to prove some properties of $f, g$

I already know the answer that $f = ax, g = a^{2}x$ so be careful! (This is from ChatGPT, and this is correct tho)


I hope someone can help me understand and enrich my knowledge about functional equations.

Nice problem!
We claim that the only solutions are $\forall x:\boxed{(f(x),g(x)) = (mx+c,(m^2-c)x + (m+1)c)}$, where $m>0, c \ge 0, m^2 \ge c$ are real numbers.

Let $P(x,y)$ denote the assertion. Also let $a = f(1), b = g(1)$. For $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^+$:
$$P(1,y): f(y+a) = f(y)+b \tag{1}$$
$$P(x,y+a): f(xy+f(x)+xa) = xf(y+a) + g(x) = xb+f(xy+f(x))$$
So we have
$$f(xy+f(x)+xa) - f(xy+f(x)) = xb \tag{2}$$
Set $x=1$ in $(2)$ and use $(1)$ to get $$f(y+2a) - f(y) - b = f(y+2a) - f(y+a) = b$$Now by a simple induction, for $z \in \Bbb N$:
$$f(y+za) - f(y) = zb \tag{3}$$
Note that we are very close to achieving linearity, however, for that, we need to extend $z$ into reals. 
Now suppose $z \in \Bbb R^+$, we claim $(3)$ is true for such $z$ too.
Indeed, write $z = k+p$, where $k = \lfloor z \rfloor$, $p>0$. Then
$$\begin{align}
f(y+za) &= f(y + pa+ka) \\
&= f(y+pa) + kb \tag{$\text{from }(3)$} \\
&= f(y+ta + pa) + (k-t)b 
\end{align}$$
where $t$ is a sufficiently large integer so that $\exists u \in \Bbb R^+$ such that $u = \frac{y+ta - f(p)}p$. Now substitute $(p,u)$ in $(2)$ to get
$$f(y+ta+pa) = f(y+ta)+pb$$
Hence $\forall z \in \Bbb R^+$: $$f(y+za) = f(y+ta) + (z-t)b = f(y)+zb$$
This implies $f$ is linear, so let $f(x) = mx+c$ and substitute in $P(x,y)$ to get $g(x)$.

The particular solution found by the OP through ChatGPT is the case $a=b$, or $c=0$.
